# Not able to copy file from docker container to host

Tags: linux, docker

I cloned a repo from GitHub with Dockerfile and ran the Docker container. I created a new file inside the container but when I try to copy from container to host using following command, I am getting an error:

```
docker cp 0ba025428be7:/project/data/a.txt ~/Desktop/

 Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/2f05ac93ba0b0695284bfa5720bee04f35fbb4e4ce200e3092478954bb912cab/ParsCit/demodata/td.txt: no such file or directory
```

I also ran docker commit after creating the file but still the same error.

Comment: try `cd ~/Desktop/ ; docker cp 0ba025428be7:/project/data/a.txt .`

Comment: Any reason you can think of that it's referring to td.txt when you're trying to copy a.txt? e.g. is this error from a different `docker cp` command? Also, what version of docker are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the content of containers is visible from the host machine.

```
docker inspect <contnair-name> | grep volume
```

After you can go in to copy your data.

Contenair data are most of time in **/var/lib/docker/volumes**